# How to know what programs are running in service layer or framework

Tags: android

I need to know what program is running. Because I need to stop backlight turn off in my application.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the Activity from dimming while the UI is displaying, use `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` for Activity window and hold a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` to keep the device running while you are not in its UI.